# iOS Autolayout for scrollview and sticky footer

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

Assume I have a layout as on image below:
[image]
Root view - is a viewController's view. I'd like to have my footer text to be

- sticked to bottom of screen, if content fits in one screen (main text is small)
- have 15pt from main text & 15 pt from bottom of screen in other cases

I understand, that I can calculate main text heigt & compare it to current screen size, but I'd like to find another way (ideally only with constraints).

Is it possible?

Comment: add your footer below the UIScrollView and show it by checking the end of the scroll in scrollviewDidScroll

Comment: @zombie It also includes a lot of logic in code

Answer (score 13):

To achieve what you are trying to do you need to set the following constraints:

**ScrollView**:
- `top`, `leading`, `trailing` and `bottom` equal to **RootView**'s `top`, `leading`, `trailing` and `bottom`

**WrapperView**:
- `top`, `leading`, `trailing` and `bottom` equal to **ScrollView**'s `top`, `leading`, `trailing` and `bottom`
- `width` equal to ScrollView's `width`
- `height` greaterThanOrEqual to ScrollView's `height`

**TextView**:
- `top`, `leading` and `trailing` equal to **WrapperView**'s `top`, `leading` and `trailing`

**FooterView**:
- `leading` and `trailing` equal to **WrapperView**'s `leading` and `trailing`
- `bottom` equal to **WrapperView**'s `bottom` (with constant 15)
- `top` greaterThanOrEqual to **TextView**'s `bottom` (with constant 15)

The key are the two constraints that use the `greaterThanOrEqual` relation: The **WrapperView** is at least as high as the **ScrollView** and the **FooterView**`s top has at least a distance of 15 from the **TextView**'s bottom.

Here are the constraints when you use a Storyboard:

[image]

And this is how you would do it programatically (using SnapKit):

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        let wrapperView = UIView()
        wrapperView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        scrollView.addSubview(wrapperView)

        let textView = UILabel()
        textView.numberOfLines = 0
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        textView.text = "You think water moves fast? You should see ice. It moves like it has a mind. Like it knows it killed the world once and got a taste for murder. After the avalanche, it took us a week to climb out. Now, I don't know exactly when we turned on each other, but I know that seven of us survived the slide... and only five made it out. Now we took an oath, that I'm breaking now. We said we'd say it was the snow that killed the other two, but it wasn't. Nature is lethal but it doesn't hold a candle to man."
        //textView.text = "You think water moves fast? You should see ice. It moves like it has a mind."
        textView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        wrapperView.addSubview(textView)

        let footer = UILabel()
        footer.textAlignment = .center
        footer.text = "Footer text"
        footer.backgroundColor = .orange
        wrapperView.addSubview(footer)

        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
             make.edges.equalTo(view)
        }

        wrapperView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(scrollView)
            make.width.equalTo(scrollView)
            make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(scrollView)
        }
        textView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.left.right.equalTo(0)
        }
        footer.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(textView.snp.bottom).offset(15)
            make.left.right.equalTo(0)
            make.bottom.equalTo(-15)
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot with long text:

[image]

Screenshot with short text:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. I used to add constraints for stackview using superview (not scroll view) and it works poorly however your decision helped me.

Comment: Good approach, seems to be working, but it gives some errors in interface builder, saying "Scroll View: Need constraints for: Y position or height"